# insert text into program

Tags: command-line

I'm fairly new at using the Terminal and Im trying to figure out how to open a program (say Safari) and insert text into the search box. I already know how to open safari using the terminal. I just want to know if there is a way to insert text into the address bar. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your browser or the graphical application you are running. If the browser give you the option, you can.

`firefox` supports this. Lets say you have just opened `firefox` from terminal, now you can use the following commands to open a new URL just like typing in the address bar:

```
firefox --new-tab gmail.com
```

will open `gmail.com` in a new tab.

```
firefox --new-window gmail.com
```

will open `gmail.com` in a new firefox window.

Check the manpage of your program (`man program`) to check if it supports this feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to quickly google something in the command line:

```
search="Hello php runner"
googlesearch=$(echo $search | sed 's/ /+/g')
firefox --new-window https://www.google.com/#q=$googlesearch
```

The second line converts blank spaces with pluses, since that is how Google deals with spaces